# rake aborted .. I can't use rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I got problem when I use rake command

rake db:create

rake aborted!

Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add following two lines to your Gemfile,

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

and run "bundle install" next.